# Understanding results from Scipy coherence function

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I have two signals that look like this:

[image]

The length of each signal is 500 years, with one data point per year.
Looking at the signals, the expected coherence should be at `0.01`, because as can be seen in the time domain - both signals have dominant frequency of 100 years. However, using scipy coherence function as follows:

```
from scipy import signal

f, Cxy = signal.coherence(y1, y2, fs=1.0, nperseg=500)
plt.semilogy(f, Cxy)
plt.xlabel('frequency [1/year]')
plt.ylabel('Coherence')
plt.show()
```

The result is this:

[image]

I don't understand a few things about the graph:

1. How did scipy created the frequency bins?
2. Why there is no peak at the 0.01 frequency as expected?
3. What is the meaning of the different peaks?

Comment: *"the expected coherence should be at 0.01"* Could you please expand on this? The choice of the window may affect the results.

Comment: I edited my question. The reason for the 0.01 is because both signals have a frequency of 100 years which is dominant.

Answer (score 2):

Coherence is a statistical quantity. It is obtained by averaging over multiple realizations of the same signal (ensemble averaging). In practice you obtain those realizations by taking slices of your signal and assume they are all equivalent, i.e., you assume your signal is stationary.

By choosing nperseg=500, which is the size of your signals, you are basically using only 1 realization and not doing any averaging. Therefore, you obtain a coherence of 1 (approximately) for all frequencies. Choose something like nperseg=50 to average 10 realizations of your signal and you should get your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a mismatch between your expectation on the coherence and scipy's coherence function.

Coherence measures how much power can be transferred from input to output in linear systems. When I look your plot, 0.01 seems to be period but period of the signal does not imply that it is the coherence is 0.01 because coherence is a ratio composed of power spectral densities. SO, before using coherence, try to check autocorrelation & crosscorrelation sequences as it is directly related with them.

So, peaks imply that it's more (un)likely to transfer power from input to output, but i don't know the relationship between your signals.

Scipy's coherence function estimates the coherence from the PSD of two signals not the Fourier transform of the signals itself via Welch's periodogram method. So, always check windowing function and sampling rate, if you are sure in your calculations.

Hope this helps